# Listview not filled with data from Volley in onCreate

Tags: android, listview, android-volley, ormlite

I'm trying to generate a list view from data together with Volley and ORMLite. The data is shown when i perform a pull to refresh or a reload of the page. When I reload the page I'm using a updateUI() function:

```
 private void updateUI() throws SQLException {
    mAdministrationList.clear();
    mAdminstrationAdapter = new AdministrationAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater(), mAdministrationList);
    mVolleyHandler.GETAdministrations();
    mAdministrationList = mAdministrationDao.queryForAll();


    mAdminstrationListView.setAdapter(mAdminstrationAdapter);
    mAdminstrationListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mAdminstrationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This function works but the list is, as mentioned above, only loaded on a pull to refresh.

My onCreate looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_administration);

    mAdminstrationListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.administrationListView);

    mProgressSpinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.administration_spinner);

    try {
        mAdministrationDao = getHelper().getAdministrationDao();
        mGlobalsDao = getHelper().getGlobalsDao();
        mGlobals = mGlobalsDao.queryForAll().get(0);

        mCurrentAdministration = mGlobals.getAdministration();
        mToken = mGlobals.getToken();
        mUser = mGlobals.getUser();

        mVolleyHandler = VolleyHandler.getInstance(this, mGlobals.getIpAddress(), mCurrentAdministration, mUser, mToken);

        updateUI();
        mAdminstrationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.administrationSwipe);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            try {
                updateUI();

                mAdminstrationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
}
```

The VolleyCall I'm making is getting the data from the API and parse it to a Administration Object, who is getting saved to the Database with ORMLite.

```
  public void ParseAdministration(String response) throws JSONException, SQLException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

    for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject object = results.getJSONObject(i);

        Administration administration = new Administration();
        administration.setId(Long.valueOf(object.getString("id")));
        administration.setName(object.getString("name"));
        administration.setAddress1(object.getString("address1"));
        administration.setAddress2(object.getString("address2"));
        administration.setPostalCode(object.getString("postalCode"));
        administration.setCity(object.getString("city"));
        administration.setCountry(object.getString("country"));

        mDatabaseHelper.saveAdministration(administration);

    }
}
```

I can't find where the problem is, so maybe some of you know what my problem is.

Thanks in Advance

EDITED:

Thanks to Shubham Goel, I have found a solution:

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mProgressSpinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.administration_spinner);
                    updateUI();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mProgressSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 3000);
```

Maybe it's a little bit dirty but it does the job. Let me know if you think there is a better solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be because in oncreate the volley loads data and takes some time to load data...till then all the updateUI functionality is performed with no data in list..before you pull to refresh the data has been loaded by the volley request and it shows up in list.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can assure that the volley call has been made before the page has been loaded?

Comment: Can you post your VolleyHandler class code here. @OrlandoSmits